# Error: "To run a ssis package outside of sql server data tools you must install [send successful email] of Integration Services or higher."

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

**NOTE** that the title of this qusetion is a verbatim error message specific to this user. The error message illustrates a bug in the dtexec application, which substitutes a user variable into the error message string. In this case, the standard message `Standard E
dition` is replaced with `send successful email`.

The 'standard' error message would be :

**Description: To run a SSIS package outside of Business Intelligence Development Studio you must install Standard Edition of Integration Services or higher.**

---

Version SSIS 2012. Package was originally 2005 ver. Package on file system.

DB Engine / Agent on Host 1, SSIS on Host 2.

Execution from Host 2 runs successfully. Execution from Host 1 gives the error in the question subject. Saw [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5158/running-an-ssis-package-without-the-ssis-service-installed), but engine and agent are installed on Host 1. Has anyone seen this? Google returns no results when searching on the exact error (subject line is exact, wording is odd in the error message).

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using the new Project Deployment model or the older Package Deployment model? SQL Agent is starting the package on Host 2 via job step of Integration Services, some command line call or a TSQL call

Comment: Old method, single dtxs package file. This is seen when executing the package from SSMS\Integration Services, no job involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSIS 2012 components had to be installed on Host 1 to resolve the issue.

*If anyone knows of a way to resolve this without installing SSIS 2012 components where they aren't intended, please post and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Since the other question was tagged with 2005, presumably the behaviour has changed since then.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error, but with the name of one of my job steps in place of ‘send successful email’. What worked for me was to restart Agent after adding my environment variable to the new server. Stupid, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try Command line to execute the package -

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtexec /FILE "\"C:\Users\amc\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Planning Project1\Planning Project1\PlanningDataLoad.dtsx\"" /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E '
```