# Running scheduled SSIS pkg with SQL Server 2012 Web Edition

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have a client with SQL Server 2012 Web Edition. I believe it has SQL Server Agent, but I see on the following Microsoft page that many integration services are not supported:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.110).aspx

My guess is that I could develop an SSIS solution and perhaps run it scheduled by calling it from DTEXEC and scheduling that as a job in the Server Agent.

I agree that getting the client on Standard Edition would be best, but if that is not do-able, can they still run a scheduled SSIS solution scheduled? (Solution is an incremental load from flat files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you attempt to run the package from dtexec, you can test this yourself, you're going to get an error that basically says you failed the licensing check and it's not going to run the packages outside the context of Visual Studio (BIDS/SSDT-BI).

Once you have a licensed for a version that supports SSIS, then you'll need to install the Integration Services Service otherwise, you'll get an error in the form of "To run a ssis package outside of sql server data tools you must install {TASK NAME} of Integration Services or higher" See also [Error: "To run a ssis package outside of sql server data tools you must install [send successful email] of Integration Services or higher."](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/49786/2131)