# Any way to import-export-migrate-save-restore a maintenance plan without having SSIS installed (and running)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis, powershell, maintenance-plans

I am having dozens of MSSQL Servers 2012 R2 on Windows Server 2008 R2 with similar setup, configuration (in virtual machines) in production.  Neither has SSIS installed.

I have to similarly maintain (migrate, restore) the same maintenance plans on all of dozens servers

[image]

Any way to import-export-migrate-save-restore maintenance plans without having SQL Server Integration Service (SSIS) and Data Tools (BIDS) installed (and running)? Though I can stage a separate server machine for them

Saw [the answer to "Running an SSIS package without the SSIS service installed"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5159/28279) but still uncertain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a working maintenance plan, which is really just an SSIS package, you can export that .dtsx file out of the database and redeploy to the next one.

For 2008/2012, those packages are stored in msdb.dbo.sysssispackages which you can verify with a [query](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/08/ssis-package-query.html)

```
;
WITH FOLDERS AS
(
    -- Capture root node
    SELECT
        cast(PF.foldername AS varchar(max)) AS FolderPath
    ,   PF.folderid
    ,   PF.parentfolderid
    ,   PF.foldername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders PF
    WHERE
        PF.parentfolderid IS NULL

    -- build recursive hierarchy
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        cast(F.FolderPath + '\' + PF.foldername AS varchar(max)) AS FolderPath
    ,   PF.folderid
    ,   PF.parentfolderid
    ,   PF.foldername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackagefolders PF
        INNER JOIN
            FOLDERS F
            ON F.folderid = PF.parentfolderid
)
,   PACKAGES AS
(
    -- pull information about stored SSIS packages
    SELECT
        P.name AS PackageName
    ,   P.id AS PackageId
    ,   P.description as PackageDescription
    ,   P.folderid
    ,   P.packageFormat
    ,   P.packageType
    ,   P.vermajor
    ,   P.verminor
    ,   P.verbuild
    ,   suser_sname(P.ownersid) AS ownername
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.sysssispackages P
)
SELECT 
    F.FolderPath
,   P.PackageName
,   F.FolderPath + '\' + P.PackageName AS PackagePath
,   P.packageFormat
,   P.packageType
,   P.vermajor
,   P.verminor
,   P.verbuild
,   P.ownername
,   P.PackageId
FROM 
    FOLDERS F
    INNER JOIN
        PACKAGES P
        ON P.folderid = F.folderid
-- uncomment this if you want to filter out the 
-- native Data Collector packages
WHERE
     F.FolderPath <> '\Data Collector';
```

You will then want to pipe that information to repeated dtutil calls much as I describe on this [SSIS Package Extract From msdb](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2011/11/ssis-package-extract-from-msdb.html#uds-search-results). Instead of the `/file` output though, you'd want to make it `/destserver thatdatabase /copy SQL;PkgName` See the answer over on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7603021/updating-deployed-ssis-package/7605044#7605044

As noted in the comments, if you used package level encryption, you will need to add a parameter for that as well `/encrypt file;"foo.dtsx";3;<somepass>` This is presented as is because I don't advocate package passwords, nor have I tested it.

Comment: Thanks. But on execution of `dtutil /sourceserver localhost /SQL "\Maintenance Plans\MaintenancePlan_daily" /copy file;.\MaintenancePlan_daily.dtsx` I am getting the error: "_The package \Maintenance Plans\MaintenancePlan_daily can not be saved to the file system since its protection level is server storage.  Use the encrypt action to change the protection level"_ And I cannot find how to pass through it

Comment: Shall try the last answer from [SSIS: Import Packages error](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e4922b02-0c9c-482e-93fd-11aa1613b6d3/ssis-import-packages-error?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Comment: I created a maintenance plan and it wasn't stored with server storage encryption. `dtutil /sourceserver localhost\dev2012 /SQL "\Maintenance Plans\POC MaintenancePlan" /copy file;".\POC MaintenancePlan.dtsx"` Any idea how I can force a maintenance plan to be encrypted to reproduce your error?

Comment: Wanted to ask a long time ago but I am not sure how to formulate and where to put my question. It is not me who who installed and administers the AD domain and Windows (Servers 2008 R2) in servers (I am also not DBA but a programmer). I guess it is something connected  either with UAC or domain policies with which I cannot meddle or even view them. Also I cannot save any files upon editing in servers. When I need to change something, I change it on my local comp and copy with replacement them to servers

Comment: Instead of /copy file;"foo.dtsx" you need /encrypt file;"foo.dtsx";3;<somepass> to get past the encryption issue.